# Using two different comparators for priority queue java

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparable

I have a class(**Graphs.java**) where I am calculating the route between a start and goal location with least distance. I am using comparable interface and overriding compareTo method to compare the elements of the priority queue based on distance of the roads. compareTo method is within **Nodes.java** class as the elements of my queue are *nodes* objects.

Now I have to write another method in Graphs.java to return a route based on fastest path not shortest. So can I add another compareTo method inside Nodes.java (may be with another name) to compare time required to traverse or some other approach to handle this second type of sorting in priority queue.

Comment: If by fastest path you mean least number of edges traversed, then you can use a simple BFS, which is faster because no priority queue is involved.

Comment: You can write multiple [`Comparator`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) to implement different comparation-methods.